Cannot get the response body in Chrome devtools extension
I'm building an extension for personal use that monitors web traffic on a certain domain (icloud.com) and sends the data to a PHP script. I have very little (next to none) experience in developing Chrome Extensions so I opted for a devtools extension after many failed attempts. This is my code right now:
manifest.json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "BytE iCloud v2",
    "description": "BytE iCloud checker v2",
    "version": "1.98",
    "devtools_page": "devtools.html"
}

devtools.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="devtools.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="byteicl"></div>
    </body>
</html> 

devtools.js (this is where the problem actually lies... probably)
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(request => {
  request.getContent((body) => {
    if (request.request && request.request.url) {
      if (request.request.method == "POST" || request.request.method == "FETCH") {
        var data = new URLSearchParams();
        data.set('ig', JSON.stringify({'url': request.request.url, 'data': request.response.content.text}));
        fetch("http://localhost:1609/icl.php", {
          method: 'POST',
          mode: 'no-cors',
          cache: 'no-cache',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          },
          body: data
        }).then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        });
      }
    }
  });
});

Just in case someone asks me, the icl php is here:
<?php
$aj = $_POST['ig'];
file_put_contents('icl.txt', date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . ": " . $aj . "\n", FILE_APPEND);

... and icl.txt looks something like this:
2024-04-26 01:49:20: {"url":"https://p50-ckdatabasews.icloud.com/database/1/com.apple.photos.cloud/production/private/records/query?remapEnums=true&getCurrentSyncToken=true&dsid=111hidden111&clientBuildNumber=2414Hotfix74&clientMasteringNumber=2414Hotfix74&clientId=personal-hidden-velue-here"}
2024-04-26 01:49:20: {"url":"https://p50-ckdatabasews.icloud.com/database/1/com.apple.photos.cloud/production/private/records/query?remapEnums=true&getCurrentSyncToken=true&dsid=111hidden111&clientBuildNumber=2414Hotfix74&clientMasteringNumber=2414Hotfix74&clientId=personal-hidden-velue-here"}
2024-04-26 01:53:22: {"url":"https://setup.icloud.com/setup/ws/1/validate?clientBuildNumber=2414Project60&clientMasteringNumber=2414B20&clientId=personal-hidden-velue-here&dsid=111hidden111"}
2024-04-26 01:53:22: {"url":"https://p50-setup.icloud.com/setup/ws/1/storageUsageInfo?clientBuildNumber=2414Project60&clientMasteringNumber=2414B20&clientId=personal-hidden-velue-here&dsid=111hidden111"}
2024-04-26 02:07:23: {"url":"https://setup.icloud.com/setup/ws/1/validate?clientBuildNumber=2414Project60&clientMasteringNumber=2414B20&clientId=personal-hidden-velue-here&dsid=111hidden111"}
2024-04-26 02:07:23: {"url":"https://p50-setup.icloud.com/setup/ws/1/storageUsageInfo?clientBuildNumber=2414Project60&clientMasteringNumber=2414B20&clientId=personal-hidden-velue-here&dsid=111hidden111"}

I'm trying to log all requests to the server, but I'm only getting the request URLs without the needed data.

Replace request.response.content.text with body

@wOxxOm Wow, I'm such an idiot. I'm sure I did that, but I reopened the tab now after implementing the change and it works! Thank you so much!
